# Custom Alarm tone in 5.1

Tags: alarm, 5.1-lollipop, custom-sounds

I am aware that by creating folder named `Alarms`, `Ringtones` and `Notifications` and placing audio files inside them will list those audio files as appropriate custom tones. However in my rooted stock Nexus 5 running Android 5.1 the alarm tones does not show the media files while it works perfectly for notification and ringtones.

Is this a bug in Android 5.1? I was able to achieve this in KitKat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for my 5.0:

- Stored the files in the Alarms folder (don't think this will be necessary)
- Go to file with ES Explorer (or other file explorer)
- Play the file with the built in media player of ES
- Tap on settings
- Set as ringtone and choose Alarm
- Go to Clock > Alarms and use your new music file as wake up alarm

Probably there is a option (just once/always) for choosing a ringtone in the Alarm menu. I think, I clicked on always by accident. (clearing cache/setting did not worked out) But this will be a pretty simple work around ;)

Comment: I am glad that this worked in my case as well (5.1).  Interesting ways to solve an issue - that's the power of community.

Comment: Just wanted to chip in to say, that the audio file *needs* to be in the `Alarms` folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Plug your phone into PC.
2. Open folder → go into internal storage → alarms. File type that has worked for me is Mp3 and M4A.

I have not found any other way for this to work. If you want to stay native to the phone and not download any apps then you have to use a computer.